# How to create balanced tree in matlab

Tags: matlab, tree, cluster-analysis, hierarchical, linkage

I'm trying to build a tree in matlab through hierarchical clustering.

I tried using the linkage function doing:

```
z=linkage(data);
dendrogram(z);
```

It worked fine but the resulting tree was very unbalanced (http://oi61.tinypic.com/6sasgl.jpg).

Is there a way of doing hierarchical clustering and obtaining a balanced tree?

Thank you in advance.

Raul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of options you can set in `linkage`, and it would be worth your time to examine them all in detail (also have a look at what sort of distance metrics other people are using for data similar to yours).

For example, using the inbuilt `fisheriris` set:

```
Z = linkage(meas); %default settings
Z2 = linkage(meas,'ward'); %Ward linkage
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a deeper look into it. But independently from the adopted metric the linkage function doesn't assure the creation of a balanced tree. I was wondering if there was a way of doing a hierarchical clustering that builds the tree bottom-up, paring each node of a level before starting to consider the next one.